# pulling a string into a textarea

Tags: php, html, css

How to enter a string from a variable into a textarea?

When i use the  it brings in the value fine. but need to have a textarea as the text would be quite long. I've got the textarea appearing but no content within it

```
 <p><b>Description:</b><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly> 



 <p><b>Description:</b><textarea name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly></textarea>
```

Comment: Use `textarea` instead of `textbox`

Comment: [Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/bst25wbt/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textarea` instead of `text` in your `description` area.Have a look: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nxwhhzos/)

```
<tr><td>
   <b>Description:</b><td><textarea rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
<tr><td>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! how would i then use it on my 'view' page. currently got this code but the textarea is not displaying my text. 
<p><b>Description:</b><textarea name="description" "<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly></textarea>

Comment: Welcome.Sounds good to hear from you.But now what you want i am not clear.Could you clear me what you want now? You can try ` <p><b>Description:</b><textarea name="<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly></textarea>`

Comment: I am trying to get the string value inside $description and put it in my textarea. It works fine with <input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly>    but obviously this text box is not big enough to display the whole paragraph

Comment: `<textarea type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>" readonly></textarea>` try this.

Comment: mm unfortunately not, i'm just getting the textarea. nothing within it